# Google maps MarkerClusterer displaying number instead of marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

it displaying a number of markers at a specific location. How can I display markers instead of a number? below is given code and output image. Please help me How can I get my expected result?

Note:

4 markers have same latitude and longitude. I want to display 4 different markers instead of a single marker.

JS Code:

```
<script>
    var map, infoBubble;

    function initialize() {
        var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5167, 13.3833);
        $('#user_latitude').val(52.5167);
        $('#user_longitude').val(13.3833);

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 3,
            center: mapCenter,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoomControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
            },
            streetViewControl: true,
            streetViewControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            minZoom: 3,
            scrollwheel: false
        };


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
        var markers = [];
        <?php foreach($pets as $pet):?>
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $pet['pet_lat']?>, <?php echo $pet['pet_long']?>),
            /*<?php //if():?>
            icon: 'http://cdn.com/my-custom-icon.png',
            <?php //else:?>
            icon: 'http://cdn.com/my-custom-icon.png',
            <?php //endif;?>*/
        });
        markers.push(marker);
        <?php endforeach;?>
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);


    }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>
```

[image]
Output

Comment: can you please explain why someone downvoted my question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know wich version of MarkerClusterer you are using ([MarkerClusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) or [MarkerClustererPlus](https://github.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus)) but it's probably the url of the default icons for the cluster that are not valid anymore.
Check in your browser dev tools, you should have 404 error on png files.

You have to initialize the MarkerCluster whith options to define the icons.

Example with MarkerClustererPlus

```
var options  = {
            ignoreHidden: true,
            clusterClass: cssClass,
            maxZoom: 19,
            styles: [
                {
                    height: 32,
                    width: 32,
                    textSize: 11,
                    url: "/myhost/myicon1.png"
                },
                {
                    height: 36,
                    width: 36,
                    textSize: 12,
                    url: "/myhost/myicon2.png"
                },
                {
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    textSize: 13,
                    url: "/myhost/myicon3.png"
                },
                {
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    textSize: 13,
                    url: "/myhost/myicon4.png"
                },
                {
                    height: 48,
                    width: 48,
                    textSize: 15,
                    url: "/myhost/myicon5.png"
                }
            ]
        };

cluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], options);
```

Comment: I want to display the same icon. How can I do this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, just provide one item in options.styles array, this style will always be picked regardless of number of markers in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the imagePath property of the MarkerClusterer correctly (to a location that contains the images for the clusters).  One possible source is the google sample:

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
   {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
```

updated (using CDN rawgit, google removed the copy in there documentation):

```
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
   {imagePath:
  "https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m""});
```

[proof of conceptr fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/u2L0yp4s/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map, infoBubble;

function initialize() {
  var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5167, 13.3833);
  $('#user_latitude').val(52.5167);
  $('#user_longitude').val(13.3833);

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: mapCenter,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
    },
    streetViewControl: true,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    minZoom: 3,
    scrollwheel: false
  };


  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var markers = [];
  //       <?php foreach($pets as $pet):?>
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5167, 13.3833),
    /*<?php //if():?>
    icon: 'http://cdn.com/my-custom-icon.png',
    <?php //else:?>
    icon: 'http://cdn.com/my-custom-icon.png',
    <?php //endif;?>*/
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5167, 13.38),
    /*<?php //if():?>
    icon: 'http://cdn.com/my-custom-icon.png',
    <?php //else:?>
    icon: 'http://cdn.com/my-custom-icon.png',
    <?php //endif;?>*/
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.51, 13.3833),
    /*<?php //if():?>
    icon: 'http://cdn.com/my-custom-icon.png',
    <?php //else:?>
    icon: 'http://cdn.com/my-custom-icon.png',
    <?php //endif;?>*/
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  //        <?php endforeach;?>
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath:
      "https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer/gh-pages/images/m",
  });



}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/googlemaps/v3-utility-library@07f15d84/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<input id="user_latitude" />
<input id="user_longitude" />
```